# Save an entry with tags

Tags: entry, tags, frontend-form

I have a project that the user choose a tag (tags are already created) and save the information.

I try save a entry which has a tag field, all the stuff saves, but the tags don't.  I try search information about that, but any where have a solution or the solution doesn't work.

I try [entry form](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entry-form).

Answer (score 2):

Hard to know without seeing some template code, but the syntax for saving existing tags on a front-end entry form looks like this:

```
<select multiple name="fields[fieldHandle][]">
    <option value="13">Tag Name One</option>
    <option value="42">Tag Name Two</option>
    <option value="144">Tag Name Three</option>
</select>
```

Replace `fieldHandle` with the actual handle of your Tags field and `13`, `42` and `144` with the actual Tag IDs.

There's a great list of examples for what front-end inputs need to look like for Craft fields here you might find useful: https://straightupcraft.com/articles/craft-cms-field-guide-twig?view=input

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version for a frontend form that grabs the tags in the specified group, displays a multiple select list and highlights any tags that are already selected for that entry.

Replace `myTagField` with the name of your tag field, and `myTagGroup` with the tag group name. Note that `entry` must be defined as well.

```
{% set field = craft.app.fields.getFieldByHandle('myTagField') %}
{% set  selectedTags = []  %}
{% for selectedTag in craft.tags.relatedTo(entry) %}
    {% set  selectedTags = selectedTags|merge([selectedTag.id])  %}
{% endfor %}
<select multiple id="{{field.handle}}" name="fields[{{field.handle}}][]">
    {% for tagOption in craft.tags.group('myTagGroup').all() %}
        <option value="{{ tagOption.id }}"{% if tagOption.id in selectedTags %}selected="selected"{%endif%}>{{tagOption.title}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

This searches a pre-built array for a value matching the `id` of each of the loaded tags. Hope this helps someone else!